# Gmail login: Google play service out of date

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

when i tried to use:

```
mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this)
        .setVisibleActivities("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity",
        "http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity").build();
```

it triggers `onConnectionFailed` and the `ConnectionResult` is:

```
ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED,
resolution=null}
```

and as a whole it says:

```
03-02 12:12:50.969: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(18431): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3025100 but found 2012110
```

So, what exactly should I update on my device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Play services is the associated features for the Play store.  You can install it directly from the web store here:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en

If you are using an emulator, Google Play Services is included in AVDs with Google APIs 4.2.2 and newer set as the platform target. I have only tested on ARM.

See [this post for details on installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000548/google-play-services-in-emulator-implementing-google-plus-login-button-etc).

Comment: But how to install it on emulator.I have no device.

Comment: Added comment to the answer on using an emulator.