# Install Google Plus App on Emulator (Android)

Tags: android, google-plus, sharing

> > I want to integrate Google Plus Sharing feature in Android Application. But for that, installation of Google Plus App is required.
> >
> > So I want to include Google Plus App in Emulator. I am using Android 4.2.2 SDK.How can I install it?

I have checked the  configuration. But I found problem here by looking at this :

> > int available = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

Here it says `SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED.` What can I do now for service updation ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Install a compatible version of the Google APIs platform. If you want
>   to test your app on the emulator, expand the directory for Android
>   4.2.2 (API 17) or a higher version, select Google APIs, and install it. Then create a new AVD with Google APIs as the platform target.
>   Note: Only Android 4.2.2 and higher versions of the Google APIs
>   platform include Google Play services.

You can read more about setting up google play services [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)

Comment: I have this configuration already..But I found problem here by looking at this : int available = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this); Here it says SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED.What can i do now for service updation ?

Comment: Have you tried: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000548/google-play-services-in-emulator-implementing-google-plus-login-button-etc

Comment: Yes I have tried this but I got exactly this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171684/gmail-login-google-play-service-out-of-date?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The Google Play Services on those emulators is simply outdated and won't be updated. Use the latest emulator with Google API level 19 (Android 4.4).

More info here: [SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED and Google play service out of date while integrating Google Plus in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284874/service-version-update-required-and-google-play-service-out-of-date-while-integr/19883764#19883764)

Answer (score 0):

A physical device to use for developing and testing because Google Play services can only be installed on an emulator with an AVD that runs Google APIs platform based on Android 4.2.2 or higher. For more detail [check this](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started#step_3_initialize_the_plusclient)