# Android Studio 1.3 RC3. Google Play services out of date. Requires 7571000 but found 6774470

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-cloud-messaging, android-sdk-tools

### Attempt History

It could be a duplicate for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30767461/150371)
I followed all the suggestions in the comments, none of them helped resolve. So i have a duplicate question with some more additional information.

### Issue

Whenever I run my app with the below mentioned spec of AVD, i get a logcat like

```
Google Play services out of date. Requires 7571000 but found 6774470.
```

### Details

These are the version of stuffs i have. Please let me know if need any info, currently I'm blocked hope any one from GCM team can help me resolve this.

> Android Studio 1.3 RC3

### Gradle

> root/gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0-beta3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

> app/gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mysample.gcm"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            //runProguard false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```

### AVD Info

[image]

### SDK Info

[image]
[image]

- EDIT: Added complete graddle files
- EDIT2: Missed mentioning that these samples are an excerpt from [Official sample for GCM](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm).

Comment: Can you post your whole `app/build.gradle` ?

Comment: Go to Application Manager in your emulator and verify the version of Google Play Services.

Comment: @YeLinAung Just added complete build.gradle.

Comment: @DanielNugent Google Play Services version in emulator is version 6.7.74 (1723905-470), its the one reported in this question 6774470.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with your project or your code, you just need to upgrade Google Play Services in your emulator.

You can easily prompt an upgrade in the `onCreate()` override for your Activity (and you should have this code in your project for end users as well).

```
int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
    if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(status)) {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this,
                100).show();
    } 
}
```

You can check the result in `onActivityResult()`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 100){
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 for quick response and suggestion. github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/… exactly what I have, but since its running in emulator, update play services not working, even though prompt shows up.

Comment: @techastute Ahh, well there's the problem.  Unfortunately there is nothing you can do except for getting a successful upgrade of Google Play Services. Just know that it's strictly an emulator issue. If you can test on a device you won't have any issues.

Comment: @techastute you might want to try [Genymotin](http://genymotion.com) + Installing GApps on them ?

Comment: @YeLinAung it looks like a worth try. But since i spent more than 3 hours trying to fix it, i would like to know what am i doing wrong? Also the process to install play service in Genymotin looks [tiresome](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-install-google-play-services-on-android-emulator-genymotion/). Have you used Genymotin+PlayService before?

Comment: @techastute Like Daniel said it's very likely that the emulator is having the lower version of Play Services ( That has been pretty problematic because some devices don't even come with Play Store and Google Apps ). However, I'd suggest to take a try with Genymotion. Better explanation about installing GApps on Genymotion can be found on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831990/how-do-you-install-google-frameworks-play-accounts-etc-on-a-genymotion-virt). Yes. I've been using Genymotion + Play Services for quite some time and it works perfectly. :)

Comment: U guys and Genymotin are awesome. +1 @YeLinAung for SO post, it was very straightforward. I will still leave this as a question to get some AVD related solution.

Comment: No AVD related solution, but Genymotion is better bet.